# Ocaml return a function from a list of tuples

Tags: list, function, ocaml

I need to convert a list into a function.  I've managed to make the list into a list of tuples.  So I have something like this now:

```
[Expr, (Expr, [[T"("; N Expr; T")"]; [N Num]; [N Expr; N Binop; N Expr]; [N Lvalue]; [N Incrop; N Lvalue]; [N Lvalue; N Incrop]]
 Lvalue, [[T"$"; N Expr]])]
```

I want the final result to look something like:

```
(Expr,
 function
   | Expr ->
       [[N Term; N Binop; N Expr];
       [N Term]]
   | Lvalue ->
       [[T"$"; N Expr]])
```

I'm mostly stuck on how I can implement the OR symbols (|).  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: This looks like an uninformed attempt at an implementation of a parser, interpreter, or a compiler, it is hard to tell which. It would help if you told us what it is you're trying to do. With high likelihood there will be a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You're describing things as if you want to generate the *source* of your function. That doesn't make a lot of sense unless you're writing some kind of preprocessing tool.

Assuming you're not working on a preprocessor, you should think about what you want the function to do, rather than the textual form it should have. You can easily get the functionality you seem to want--it basically works like the `List.assoc` function. But you can't do it by creating a certain textual form for the function at runtime.

Here's a function that translates a list of pairs into a lookup function:

```
# let makeLookup pairs = fun x -> List.assoc x pairs;;
val makeLookup : ('a * 'b) list -> 'a -> 'b = <fun>
# let f = makeLookup [(1, "yes"); (2, "no")];;
val f : int -> string = <fun>
# f 1;;
- : string = "yes"
# f 2;;
- : string = "no"
#
```

(In fact `makeLookup` is the same as `List.assoc` with its parameters reversed.)